# Проверка на существование файла шаблона Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет! Создаю свой первый сайт на Wordpress.

Возникла необходимость сделать проверку на существование файла шаблона в папке темы. Например - существует ли 'author.php'. Можно ли это сделать штатной функцией?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что такое штатная функция, но код проверки наличия файла выглядит так:

```
$filename = 'author.php';
if (file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $filename)) {
    echo 'Файл ' . $filename . ' существует';
} else {
    echo 'Файл ' . $filename . ' не существует';
}
```